# Stop function when it says 'GREEN'

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am making the button activate the function to change the color to a random color, but when it's green, i want the button to stop changing the color.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function roll1() {
rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
die = document.getElementById("die1");

if (rand >= 1 && rand <= 3) {
    die.innerHTML = "<p>'GREEN'<\/p>";
} else if (rand == 4 || rand == 5) {
    die.innerHTML = "<p>'GREEN'<\/p>";
} else if (rand == 6) {
    die.innerHTML = "<p>'RED'<\/p>"
}
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<button onclick="roll1()">Roll Dice</button>

<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:55px; height:55px;">

<p id="die1">'YELLOW'</p></td>

</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

i also don't want the button to disappear, because it still needs to do something else that is not in this code.

Comment: Do you mean that if the die is green, pressing the button will have no effect?

Comment: You already know when the button is "green", you set the text to green? Is this what you're trying to do [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T5xEy/) ??

Comment: no, i mean that if the _output_ is 'GREEN' the button will no longer activate the function, but still be pressable

Comment: A simple flag would do that, see salexch's answer !

Comment: Or just check if the innerHTML matched the word green, so you don't need an extra flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stop_flag = false;

function roll1() {
    if (stop_flag)
        return false;

    rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    die = document.getElementById("die1");

    if (rand >= 1 && rand <= 3) { 
        stop_flag = true;
        die.innerHTML = "<p>'GREEN'<\/p>";
    } else if (rand == 4 || rand == 5) {
        die.innerHTML = "<p>'GREEN'<\/p>";
    } else if (rand == 6) {
        die.innerHTML = "<p>'RED'<\/p>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the attribute `disabled`, so the button is no longer clickable.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but based on the comments, the button should remain clickable. I removed my answer...